# How can i diagnose Apache errors on Wordpress and on shared hosting? Mainly LimitInternalRecursion

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, shared-hosting

I have few problems with my wordpress site which is building high number of Apache errors.

[Wed Mar 06 18:21:14.844492 2019] [core:error] [pid 28034:tid 140475830826752] [client] AH00125: Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Others are
- connection resetted by peer ([pid 17983:tid 140475847612160] - ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function)
- Broken pipe: [client] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function

But the worst is LimitInternalRecursion which is appering whole day whole night thousand times

Earlier i thought that i repaired this problem, by deleting google sitemaps, disabling google analytics and yoast seo (which is giving these maps)

My htacess is default:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

+w3 total cache codes and rewrites (paste it here?)

I have redirection from other domain and in other htacess one line:
Redirect 301 / http://swiadomosc-zwiazkow.pl/

(i'm not using www prefix)

I have disabled all plugins and problem persists. Maybe something with database?

Problems are more often when im using wp_admin